# How to insert and update value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoid, criteria

```
    {_id :1,    
    name : ABC,
address :India,
    ph : { 9856235412, 23654122 }
}
```

**1. How to add one more value of Ph?**

means I have to add value 02152123, result should have

```
{_id :1,    
    name : ABC,
address :India,
    ph : { 9856235412, 23654122, 02152123 }
}
```

**2. How to update value 9856235412 of Ph?**

, result should have

```
{_id :1,    
    name : ABC,
address :India,
    ph : { 888212225, 23654122, 02152123 }
}
```

Please help me criteria in java, i beginer for mongo db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming ph is actually an array and not an object structure, so the data structure is:

`{_id :1, name : ABC,
   address :India,
   ph : [ 9856235412, 23654122 ]
}`

This should do it:

`db.collection.update({$push:{ph : 02152123}}, {_id:1})`

Answer (score 1):

`ph : { 9856235412, 23654122 }` is not a valid syntax, if it's an object it should be:

```
ph: { someKey: 9856235412, anotherKey: 23654122 }
```

And if it's an array it should be:

```
ph : [ 9856235412, 23654122 ]
```

Assuming it's an array like this:

```
{
  _id :1,    
  name : ABC,
  address :India,
  ph : [ 9856235412, 23654122 ]
}
```

**1. How to add one more value of Ph?**

Answer:

To add one element:

```
db.collection.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $addToSet: { Ph: 02152123 } }
)
```

To add multiple elements:

```
db.collection.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $addToSet: { Ph: { $each: [ 123, 456, 789 ] } } }
 )
```

**2. How to update value 9856235412 of Ph to 888212225?**

Answer:

```
db.collection.update(
  { _id: 1, Ph: 9856235412 },
  { $set: { "Ph.$": 888212225 } }
)
```